# Android BroadcastReceiver startActivity issue

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, start-activity

I have a simple application, when user toggle the alarm settings on,
my application will schedule a task to show an activity (PopupActivity) at midnight.

The PopupActivity is not the main activity of my application. I have tested on some devices and found that there is no problems. 
However, some of my users reported that when the alarm trigger, my application will launch both the PopupActivity and the MainActivity.

How can I avoid the MainActivity launched when the alarm is trigger?

The following is my code snap:

```
public void scheduleAlarm() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, AlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)  {
    Intent newIntent = new Intent();
    newIntent.setClass(context, PopupActivity.class);
    newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    newIntent.putExtra(PopupActivity.KEY_MESSAGE, "Popup");
    context.startActivity(newIntent);
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
...
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/APP_NAME"
    android:configChanges="orientation|locale"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>

<receiver 
    android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />

<activity
    android:name=".PopupActivity"
    android:label="@string/APP_NAME"
    android:configChanges="orientation|locale"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
...
```

Comment: When your `Alarm` Trigger it'll load only `PopupActivity`..

Comment: @Manish I have tested and it should be like that. However some clients reported that besides the PopupActivity, the MainActivity is also launched at the Alarm Trigger, I have no idea how this happen and how I can fix it.